# How do I detect intersections with elipses in java

Tags: java, math, collision-detection

I'm trying to make a smash bros like game and I wanted hitboxes to be elipses since I can see where they collide better and move them in a more accurate direction and I'm using the formula ((x-h)^2)/a^2) +
((y-k)^2)/a^2) = 1 to do this but I can't get it to work

I tried having it iterate through each x value in the domain of the first elipse and compare it to every domain value of the second elipse and if any x values were equal I had it check if they shared a y value and it works at some points but not others and I was wondering if anyone knew why

```
public double[] intersects(Hitbox h1)
    {
        double d[] = {-1, -1};
        for(double q = h-(a/2.0); q <= h+(a/2.0); q += 10)
        {
            for(double w = h1.getH()-(h1.getA()/2.0); w <= h1.getH()+(h1.getA()/2.0); w += 10)
              {
                int ha = h1.getA();
                int hb = h1.getB();
                int hh = h1.getH();
                int hk = h1.getK();
                
                 if(Math.abs(q-w) < 10)
                 {
                     long ab = (a*a)*(b*b);
                    System.out.println( q + " \t" + w);
                    System.out.println("ab\t" + ab);
                    long bb = (int)((b*b)*((q-h)*(q-h)));
                    System.out.println("bb\t" + bb);
                    double y1 = k + Math.sqrt((ab-bb)/(a*a));
                    System.out.println("y1\t" + y1);
                    double negy1 = k - Math.sqrt((ab-bb)/(a*a));
                    System.out.println("negy1\t" + negy1);
        
                    ab = (ha*ha)*(hb*hb);
                    System.out.println("ab2\t" + ab);
                    bb = (int)((hb*hb)*((w-hh)*(w-hh)));
                    System.out.println("bb2\t" + bb);
                    double y2 = hk + Math.sqrt((ab-bb)/(ha*ha));
                    System.out.println("y2\t" + y2);
                    double negy2 = hk - Math.sqrt((ab-bb)/(ha*ha));
                    System.out.println("negy2\t" + negy2);
                    
                    
                    if(Math.abs(y2-y1) < 30 ||Math.abs(negy2-y1) < 30)
                    {
                      d[0] = q;
                      d[1] = y1;
                      latestIntersection = d;
                      System.out.println("fadonbhfabdfbnaodf");
                      return d;
                    }
                    if(Math.abs(y2-negy1) < 30 ||Math.abs(negy2-negy1) < 30)
                    {
                      d[0] = q;
                      d[1] = negy1;
                      latestIntersection = d;
                      System.out.println("fadonbhfabdfbnaodf");
                      return d;
                    }
                 }
              }
        }
        latestIntersection = d;
        return d;
    }
```

edit:

here's solution

```
  public class Hitbox {

    private int h, k, a, b, startx, starty;
    private double[] latestIntersection = {-1,-1};
    
    public Hitbox(int h, int k, int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.h = h;
        this.k = k*-1;
    }
    
    public double[] intersects(Hitbox h1)
    {
        double d[] = {-1, -1};
        for(double q = 1; q <= 360; q+=.5)
        {
            double f = 0;
            if(a > b)
                f = Math.sqrt((a*a)-(b*b));
            else
                f = Math.sqrt((b*b)-(a*a));
            
            double e = f/a;
            
            double top = (a*a)*(1-(e*e));
            double bottom = 1-((e*e)*(Math.cos(q)*Math.cos(q)));
            
            double r1 = Math.sqrt(top/bottom);
            
            double x1 = r1*Math.cos(q);
            double y1 = r1*Math.sin(q);
            x1 += h;
            y1 += k;
            
            for(double w = 0; w <= 360; w+=.5)
              {
                double a2 = h1.getA();
                double b2 = h1.getB();
                
                double f2 = 0;
                
                if(a2 > b2)
                    f2 = Math.sqrt((a2*a2)-(b2*b2));
                else
                    f2 = Math.sqrt((b2*b2)-(a2*a2));
                
                double e2 = f2/a2;
                
                double top2 = (a2*a2)*(1-(e2*e2));
                double bottom2 = 1-((e2*e2)*(Math.cos(w)*Math.cos(w)));
                
                double r2 = Math.sqrt(top2/bottom2);
                
                double x2 = r2*Math.cos(w);
                double y2 = r2*Math.sin(w);
                x2 += h1.getH();
                y2 += h1.getK();
               
                
                if(Math.abs(x2-x1) < 1 && Math.abs(y2-y1) < 1)
                {
                    d[0] = x1;
                    d[1] = y2;
                    latestIntersection = d;
                    return d;
                }
                
                
              }
        }
        latestIntersection = d;
        return d;
    }
    
    
    public double[] getOppositeInteresection()
    {
        double d[] = {-1,-1};
        if(latestIntersection != d)
        {
            if(latestIntersection[0]-h < 0)
            {
                d[0] = latestIntersection[0]-h + (((latestIntersection[0]-h)*2)*-1);
                System.out.println(d[0]);
                d[0] += h;
            }
            else if(latestIntersection[0]-h > 0)
            {
                d[0] = latestIntersection[0]-h - ((latestIntersection[0]-h)*2);
                System.out.println(d[0]);
                d[0] += h;
            }
            if(latestIntersection[1]-k < 0)
            {
                d[1] = latestIntersection[1]-k + (((latestIntersection[1]-k)*2)*-1);
                System.out.println(d[1]);
                d[1] += k;
                return d;
            }
            else if(latestIntersection[1]-k > 0)
            {
                d[1] = latestIntersection[1]-k - ((latestIntersection[1]-k)*2);
                System.out.println(d[1]);
                d[1] += k;
                return d;
            }
        }
        
        return d;
    }
    
    

  public int getA()
  {
    return a;
  }
  public int getB()
  {
    return b;
  }

  public int getH()
  {
    return this.h;
  }

  public int getK()
  {
    return this.k;
  }

public void setH(int h)
{
    this.h = h;
}

public void setK(int k)
{
    this.k = k;
}

public void setA(int a)
{
    this.a = a;
}

public void setB(int b)
{
    this.b = b;
}
  
  
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using parts of the `Shape` API, which already provides this kind of functionality?

Comment: I'm doing this for a comp sci class and we never learned how to do that so I don't know if my teacher would like that. I can use packages and stuff that we haven't learned but I think a whole API would be too much

Comment: They're built in - just saying, the wheels already been invited.  If it was me, I might have a quick look at the code behind it and see if it's adaptable to your needs ;)

Comment: Ah i see, it looks like a lot of it is with rectangles and not ellipses but I'll check it out, thanks

Comment: [`Ellipse2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html)?  You could even make you're shapes with [`Path2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to come up with an exact mathematical formula on whether two ellipses intersect. This answer would be easier on http://math.stackexchange.com where I would have proper mathematicall typesetting. But I'll try to be clear here as well.

I assume you have a typo in your formula, and that you want `a` as one semi-axis and `b` as the other, not `a` in both cases. I assume your formula actually is

```
(x-h)²/a² + (y-k)²/b² = 1
```

which can also be written in [matrix representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections) as

```
          ⎡ b²     0         -b²h      ⎤   ⎡x⎤
[x y 1] * ⎢ 0      a²        -a²k      ⎥ * ⎢y⎥ = 0
          ⎣-b²h   -a²k   a²k²+b²h²-a²b²⎦   ⎣1⎦
```

The zeros in that matrix account for the fact that your ellipse is aligned with the coordinate axes. Some other readers might be dealing with rotated ellipses, in which case you would get an even more general form of this matrix, with non-zero entries everywhere but still symmetric.

If you have two different ellipses, you get two different matrices. Let's call them `M₁` and `M₂`. Then `M₁ + λM₂` is a linear combination of these two matrices. It represents a conic section which shares the same four points of intersection with the two given ellipses. (Some of these intersections might have complex coordinates, so you don't really see them.) Among these linear combinations are three special [degenerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic) cases, where the conic section turns into a pair of lines. These are characterized by `det(M₁ + λM₂) = 0`. This is a cubic (i.e. third degree) polynomial in `λ`.

Now the point between the two ellipses intersecting one another and them not intersecting is a situation where they touch in a single point. That single point has algebraic multiplicity two, which means in the formulas it corresponds to two of the four points of intersection being in the same place. Which in turn means that two of the degenerate conics are in fact the same. Which means that the cubic polynomial in `λ` has a zero of multiplicit greater than 1. Which means that the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Discriminant) of that polynomial is zero.

If the discriminant is zero at the point where the two ellipses touch, chances are that the sign of the discriminant can tell you whether the two ellipses are disjoint or whether they have more than that single point in common. A bit of experimentation should tell you which sign is which.

But there is a caveat here: the transition from two (real) points of intersection to four points of intersection again entails a touching situation, where two points are in the same location and the discriminant is zero. Moving through that situation will again change the sign of the discriminant. So while you can use the sign of the discriminant to distinguish between zero points of intersection and two points of intersection, it won't help to distinguish zero points of intersections from four points of intersection. It also won't distinguish between zero points of intersection because the ellipses don't overlap and zero points of intersection because one of the ellipses fully contains the other. If your hit boxes move so fast that they could go from no intersection to four points of intersection or full containment in a single step, this might be a problem for the approach I suggested. I've asked a [Math StackExchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4666719/35416) of my own trying to get some ideas for how to improve this.

I'll not write up the formula of the discriminant in your case, because if you go from the initial variables to that equation you'd find it has total degree 32 in those variables. But if you do a careful step-by-step computation you should be able to get there within reasonable amount of effort, first to a matrix with linear terms, then to cubic terms for each part of the determinant, which you can combine to a single cubic, and then you can apply the known fixed formula `18abcd-4b³d+b²c²-4ac³-27a²d²` for a general cubic `aλ³+bλ²+cλ+d`. Keep in mind that you will get some really large numbers, so you should use double arithmetic as integer overflow is a very likely problem.